# How to set mouse effct at image icon

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do the same mouse effect like this **contact us** button at discover field of this [link](https://www.materials.manchester.ac.uk/). But I can't do the same system and the title can't aligning at right side of the button. Can anyone help me to do the same **Discover** section like list `[link][1]`?

```
    <div>
   <a href="#">
   <figure> <img src="http://demo.mofizagrofood.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/ph2.png" alt="image"> </figure>

  </a> 
  <h2>
  Contact Us 
  </h2>
  </div>

figure{
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

figure img{
   display:inline-block;
   width: 60px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Demo [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Zaman_/wp7512x8/10/)

Comment: As you have a page with the same effect you want to achieve, have you checked their code first? What isn't working exactly for you? You can use the browser inspector to check the `<a class="fourcolRigid" href="/connect/contact/">` element and its style. With force state -> :hover (at least on Google Chrome) you can also see how the image is switched (it's a sprite https://webassets.manchester.ac.uk/faculty/fse/rwd-assets/images/design/icons-discover.png and they use background-position to move it)

Comment: .contact css is not working. I inspect the elements and copy the css file but don't understand the image switching system. here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/Zaman_/yg45w6s1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'transform: translateY' makes the images slide up and down. 'display: flex' on parent makes its children aligned left to right. Try this.
https://codepen.io/hridoy569/pen/WYPXNj

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="#" >
   <figure> 
     <img class="img1" src="" alt="image1"> 
     <img class="img2" src="" alt="image2"> 
   </figure>
  </a> 
  <h2> Contact Us  </h2>
</div>


body{
  background: White;
}

.box{
  width: 350px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box h2{

}

figure{
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background: #ccc;
}

figure img{
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
}

.box:hover .img1{
              transform: translateY(-100%);
            transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.box:not( :hover ) .img1{ 
              transform: translateY(0%);
            transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
.box:hover .img2{
              transform: translateY(-100%);
            transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.box:not( :hover ) .img2{ 
              transform: translateY(0%);
            transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much